# Какие сервера использовать для создания приложения на Python

Tags: python, сервер, websocket, kivy

Какие сервера или протоколы я могу использовать для отображения продуктов компании, например в Python Kivy?
Раньше я использовал протокол FTP для этого, но только чтобы протестировать, думаю это был неуместный вариант.
P.S Пишу код для компании у которой нет сайта, мне нужно расположить на сервере продукты и отобразить их в Python Kivy

Comment: http, Flask-RESTful or Django REST

Comment: т.е достаточно поднять http сервер как минимум?

Comment: Посмотрите `Flask`, он очень простой. Да, достаточно поднять `Flask`, отдавать с него `json` и забирать его `http` запросом через `requests`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое